# How to run PhantomJS from Tomcat web app

Tags: linux, tomcat, grails, groovy, phantomjs

I'm trying to run PhantomJS from a Grails application running on a Tomcat 7 instance on Linux (Ubuntu 13.04).

I'm sure PhantomJS is installed correctly because I can execute it from the command line. I'm using it to make a screen capture of a web page (http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).

When I run the command from the command line, it works great, using user root:

```
phantomjs /home/user/captureScreen.js "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/chart" "/home/user/07012014050636114.png"
```

I believe there is no need to share the JS code since it's working fine from the command line.

The problem is that when I run the same command from the web-app (Grails), it just returns with a 0 value, which tells me everything ran fine, but it's not creating the PNG file neither returning an error.

I'm calling the command from Groovy, this way:

```
String path = "phantomjs pathToJs.... etc"
def process = path.execute()
process.waitForOrKil(5000) // This runs in 1 to 2 seconds in the command line
println process.exitValue()
```

I tried adding write permissions to the tomcat7 user to the folder where the JS file and where the image is written but still it didn't work but I still believe it's something related to permissions

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to print anything from the JS, and capture it back in Grails and write it to standard output to see if the script is launched ? have you tried to write the absolute pat of all files (including phantomJS) in Grails ?

Comment: Hi Grooveek, yeah! I just tried those things you mention about half an hour ago: I added some output to the JS script and was able to confirm that it's running properly I also added the full path for phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs , other paths were absolute already. One funny thing, if I run the "date" command I can catch the date in the output but if I run the "time" command I get an error: "Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]"

Comment: date is a binary `/bin/date`, `time` is a built-in shell command. Maybe it could be the reason for the difference. Try to execute it with `/bin/sh -c time`

Comment: As for command execution, I've had problem with pure string notation. Have you tried the array syntax `["/usr/binphantomjs","/home/user/captureScreen.js","http://xx.xx.xx.xx/chart","/home/user/07012014050636114.png"].execute()` ?

Comment: Hi @Groveek. I just came here to mark this question as answered since I found out that what you suggest, of using an array of strings, made it work. I was not aware of your comment. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Nice of you ;-) Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for command execution, we experienced problem in Grails applications concerning pure string notation. Using the array syntax

```
   ["/usr/binphantom/js","/home/user/captureScreen.js","http://xx.xx.xx.xx/chart","‌​/home/user/07012014050636114.png"].execute()
```

made the thing work. I think it has to do with shell expansion which differs on how strings are handled in Groovy.